# I want to know why my code has low performance when using compile in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, compilation, torch, slowdown

I have a few questions:

1. I think that the Compile () method should be used to improve performance, but in my code, If I use Compile, it takes almost 2 to 30% more time than when not in use. Can you tell me what the problem in my code is?
2. If I use the compile in my Bert pre-training model, the following errors occur and it slows down dozens of times. Can you tell me what caused this error?

### Error List

1. torch._dynamo.convert_frame: [WARNING] torch._dynamo hit config.cache_size_limit (64)
   function: 'forward' (/home/mj/.../bert.py:287)
   reasons:  ___check_obj_id(self, 139626116174448)
   to diagnose recompilation issues, see https://pytorch.org/docs/master/dynamo/troubleshooting.html.
2. torch._inductor.utils: [WARNING] using triton random, expect difference from eager

<-
Error List

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import random

import time
import numpy as np


device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
torch.manual_seed(1234)
np.random.seed(1234)

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()

        self.sequential = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(stride=2, kernel_size=3),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(stride=2, kernel_size=3),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(8),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=128*8*8, out_features=10))


    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.sequential(x)
        return out

# model1 = NeuralNetwork()
# model2 = NeuralNetwork()
model1 = torchvision.models.resnet18()
model2 = torchvision.models.resnet18()
model1.to(device='cuda')
model2.to(device='cuda')
model1 = torch.compile(model1)
model2 = torch.compile(model2)

def cifar10_cnn():
    epochs = 5        
    batch_size = 64         
    report_period = 100 
    tr_count = 0           
    te_count = 0        
    data_root = "/data/" 

    torch.set_float32_matmul_precision('high')

    tr_dset = datasets.CIFAR10(root=data_root, train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
    te_dset = datasets.CIFAR10(root=data_root, train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

    tr_loader = DataLoader(tr_dset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    te_loader = DataLoader(te_dset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model1.parameters(), lr=1e-3)


    start_time = time.time()

    for i in range(epochs):
        print(f"\nEpoch {i + 1}/{epochs}\n------------------------------")
        train(tr_loader, model1, loss_fn, optimizer, report_period, start_time)
        print(f"\nTest started with {len(te_loader)} data:")
        test(te_loader, model2, loss_fn, start_time)

def train(dataloader, model1, loss_fn, optimizer, report_period, start_time):
    running_loss = 0.0
    train_loss= 0.0
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

        pred = model1(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        train_loss = running_loss / len(dataloader)

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f} [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")

    print(f"train_loss: {train_loss}")


def test(dataloader, model2, loss_fn, start_time):

    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    num_batches = len(dataloader)
    model2.eval()
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

            pred = model1(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()

            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()
    test_loss /= num_batches
    correct /= size

    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100 * correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    cifar10_cnn()
    print("Done!\n")
    print(f"running time: {time.time()-start}")
```

First, I tried to compile one model and run the train and test, and there was an error related to the Differentiation (or gradient), so I separated the compile model for train and the compile model for test.

Second, I tried using the model provided by torchvision because I wanted to see if the model I implemented was a problem, but it is equally slow.

Third, I tried to use big model because I think the slow-down may caused by unnecessary compiling-time with small model, but the same result comes.

Comment: It seems to me that you are also counting the compiling time into your total time which is probably not the most fair comparison. You should probably only measure the forward time differences.